# How to copy files from one folder to another existing folder Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to move the contents of one folder to another, Ive tried using a combo of os and shutil, but Ive ran into some issues. To clarify I want to move /Users/jcrd/Documents/screenshots to /Users/jcrd/Documents/Photos where Documents/Photos already exists and has files within it. Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Please provide [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without it nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Do you want `screenshots` itself to still be a directory in the distination or just its files? Are their subdirectories in screenshots that need to be copied?

Comment: Does [shutil.copytree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) work for you, and if not, can you detail the problem? Posting your program is an important part of solving the problem.

Comment: @sophros past two questions I posted had code and neither got solved, so I took a different approach. for something so important that no one would be able to help me without it, I got an answer much quicker than with it.

Comment: @tdelaney past 2 questions have code, neither got answered, had to take a different approach

Comment: I peeked at your other question and there is no way it would have been answered without the source code. You were asked to print both src and dest and since people didn't see that, they just surfed on by. There are a lot of questions on Stackoverflow and unfortunately they do not all get the attention they deserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import shutil, os, glob


def moveAllFilesinDir(srcDir, dstDir):
# Check if both the are directories
if os.path.isdir(srcDir) and os.path.isdir(dstDir) :
    # Iterate over all the files in source directory
    for filePath in glob.glob(srcDir + '\*'):
        # Move each file to destination Directory
        shutil.move(filePath, dstDir);
else:
    print("srcDir & dstDir should be Directories")


sourceDir = '/Users/jcrd/Documents/screenshots'
destDir =  '/Users/jcrd/Documents/Photos'

moveAllFilesinDir(sourceDir,destDir)
```

Comment: thank you! will try it in a few